# Result column widths with derived tables and rollup

Tags: mysql, group-by, column-width, rollup, mysql-5.5

Consider these mysql queries:

```
create temporary table t (a tinyint); insert into t values (1),(1),(2);

select * from t;
-- +------+
-- | a    |
-- +------+
-- |    1 |
-- |    1 |
-- |    2 |
-- +------+

select c,count(*) from (select a,count(*) c from t group by a) u
  group by c;
-- +---+----------+
-- | c | count(*) |
-- +---+----------+
-- | 1 |        1 |
-- | 2 |        1 |
-- +---+----------+
```

Why, in the first table of results, above, does `a` take up four characters' width, whereas, in the second, `c` takes up only one character's width?

```
select c,count(*) from (select a,count(*) c from t group by a) u
  group by c with rollup;
-- +---+----------+
-- | c | count(*) |
-- +---+----------+
-- | 1 |        1 |
-- | 2 |        1 |
-- | NULL |        2 |
-- +---+----------+
```

In the last table of results, above, `NULL` is wider than the width allotted to it. Is this a bug or intended behavior? If it's intended, why?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug/limitation of the mysql client.

The mysql client normally does a good job padding columns based on the longest value in the column, but I've noticed in the past that it doesn't pad properly with multi-byte string characters, and as you point out it doesn't pad properly when you use `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` if the longest value in the column is shorter than 4 characters.

Comment: That answers my second question (and thanks, and +1), but any idea about my first?

Comment: I think the MySQL client applies a minimum level of padding for column values, but does not do the same for the output of aggregate functions. So `a` is padded to 4 characters even though the longest value is 1 char long, but `c` being a result of the `count()` function is padded based on the actual longest value, which is 1 in your case.